# Error setting up Blowfish authentication in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get my application to use Blowfish for authentication. This is what I have set up so far.

In my AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Blowfish' => array(
                'scope' => array(
                    'User.is_active' => true
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In my `User` model:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {               
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], 'blowfish');
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I followed this link to set up blowfish: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords.

The error I get is `hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: blowfish [CORE/Cake/Utility/Security.php, line 109]`. The error is self-explanatory but I don't understand why it can't find the hashing algorithm since I added Blowfish to the `authenticate` array in the `Auth` component.

The error is triggered by

```
$this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = Security::hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password'], 'blowfish');
```

in the User::beforeSave() function.

Output for `print_r(mcrypt_list_algorithms());`:

```
Array ( [0] => cast-128 [1] => gost [2] => rijndael-128 [3] => twofish [4] => arcfour [5] => cast-256 [6] => loki97 [7] => rijndael-192 [8] => saferplus [9] => wake [10] => blowfish-compat [11] => des [12] => rijndael-256 [13] => serpent [14] => xtea [15] => blowfish [16] => enigma [17] => rc2 [18] => tripledes )
```

Comment: Run `print_r(mcrypt_list_algorithms());` if you don't see 'Blowfish' listed then it has not been enabled on the server.

Comment: Hi. Blowfish is listed in the array.

Comment: Can you update your question showing the output of the above line at the end of the question?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using? Blowfish isn't supported in versions older than CakePHP 2.3 as stated in the documentation; [Using Bcrypt for passwords](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords)

Comment: If you look inside the source, you can see that CakePHP 2.2.8 will try [this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.2.8/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L109), CakePHP 2.3.5 will use `crypt()` in stead of `hash()` as can be seen [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.5/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using CakePHP 2.2 while blowfish support is available only in 2.3.

Comment: Upgrade to 2.3 and you'll be fine. ;)

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-BlowfishAuthenticate.html),  you must configure AuthComponent to use it via the AuthComponent::$authenticate setting:

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
        'Blowfish' => array(
                'scope' => array('User.active' => 1)
        )
)
```

If you still have issues, feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I'd imagine that leaving your version number in your question would be helpful.